# Exception thrown when constructing CGRect

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, cgrect, bounding-box

I am making a game in which the player goes up to the exit and is transported to the next level. When I compile the project, I get the message: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 2, address = 0x791)`

I use this code to set up the exit:

```
_exit = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"exit.png"];
    CGPoint exitTileCoord = ccp(908, 980);
    CGPoint exitTilePos = [self positionForTileCoord:exitTileCoord];
    _exit.position = exitTilePos;
    [_batchNode addChild:_exit];
```

and I check whether the player has hit the exit with this code:

```
CGRect tankBoundingBox = CGRectMake(_tank.position.x - _tank.contentSize.width/2, _tank.position.y + _tank.contentSize.height, _tank.contentSize.width, _tank.contentSize.height);
CGRect exitBoundingBox = CGRectMake(_exit.position.x - _exit.contentSize.width/2, _exit.position.y + _exit.contentSize.height, _exit.contentSize.width, _exit.contentSize.height);
for (Tank *enemy in _enemyTanks) {
                if (CGRectIntersectsRect(sprite.boundingBox, enemy.boundingBox)) {

                    [childrenToRemove addObject:sprite];
                    enemy.hp--;
                    if (enemy.hp <= 0) {
                        [_enemyTanks removeObject:enemy];
                        [childrenToRemove addObject:enemy];
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            }
```

I get the error at the line where I set up the exitBoundingBox, but not the tankBoundingBox. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

If it's any help, I am using [Ray Wenderlich's tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6888/how-to-make-a-multi-directional-scrolling-shooter-part-2) to do this, and I copied the code exactly how he had it on his website (although I added in the BoundingBoxes).

Comment: what do you see when you nslog each of those float values you are using to construct your cgrect exitbounding box??

Comment: I got a really large number, so I took the `ccp(908, 908)` and changed it to `ccp(10,10).` That gave me the origin of 320.000000, 1296.000000. Is that the way that ccp works?

Comment: not sure how ccp works, but it looks like one of the values you are using to construct the cgrect is dirty.

Comment: All right. Would you like to put that in an answer so it can be accepted?

Comment: thanks! Hope it helped solve the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments for the OP:

Not sure how ccp works, but it looks like one of the values you are using to construct the cgrect is dirty.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you are building a CGRect using the positions of some objects. Well , actually the problem is that one of those objects that you get the position of gets released. You should use NSZombie to detect which one and fix problem.
[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5387006/624091) a reference that tells how to do that.

EDIT: I suspect the tank object to be the problem but I have to see more code on that.
EDIT2: `ccp` is defined as `CGRectMake`. So there's no difference.